# how to connect my combox with textbox

Tags: c#, .net

i am working on VC#.net

i have connected my combox with my database

when the combox change's the value then my textbox should show the corresponding value 
in the textbox

Comment: Is this a web application or windows?

Comment: You need to specify whether this is webforms, Winforms or WPF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to subscribe to SelectionChanged event of your ComboBox, then in eventhandler method use the following

```
if (comboBox.SelectedItem == null) 
{
   textBox.Text = string.Empty; //or any default value
   return;
}
textBox.Text = comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook up the SelectedIndexChanged event.  Depending on whether this is a WinForms or Web App will determine the exact code but ultimately they're pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use binding to do that.

```
txtbox.DataBindings.Add("Text", comboBox, "Text")
```